# Extract text from pdf using zlib

Tags: c++, objective-c, macos, pdf, zlib

I am using that function to find a text in the pdf file and replace that text with another text. The problem is when I make inflate and then change the text and deflate, in the final pdf some texts or graphics sometimes are missed. This is an error in my code or zlib library does not support this compression or something?

```
// Open the PDF source file:
FILE *pdfFile = fopen([sourceFile cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding], "rb");

if (pdfFile) {
    // Get the file length:
    int fseekres = fseek(pdfFile, 0, SEEK_END);

    if (fseekres != 0) {
        fclose(pdfFile);
        return nil;
    }

    long filelen = ftell(pdfFile);
    fseekres = fseek(pdfFile, 0, SEEK_SET);

    if (fseekres != 0) {
        fclose(pdfFile);
        return nil;
    }

    char *buffer = new char[filelen];
    size_t actualread = fread(buffer, filelen, 1, pdfFile);

    if (actualread != 1) {
        fclose(pdfFile);
        return nil;
    }

    bool morestreams = true;

    while (morestreams) {
        size_t streamstart = [self findStringInBuffer:buffer search:(char *)"stream" buffersize:filelen];
        size_t streamend = [self findStringInBuffer:buffer search:(char *)"endstream" buffersize:filelen];

        [self saveFile:buffer len:streamstart + 7 fileName:[destFile cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

        if (streamstart > 0 && streamend > streamstart) {
            streamstart += 6;

            if (buffer[streamstart] == 0x0d && buffer[streamstart + 1] == 0x0a) {
                streamstart += 2;
            } else if (buffer[streamstart] == 0x0a) {
                streamstart++;
            }

            if (buffer[streamend - 2] == 0x0d && buffer[streamend - 1] == 0x0a) {
                streamend -= 2;
            } else if (buffer[streamend - 1] == 0x0a) {
                streamend--;
            }

            size_t outsize = (streamend - streamstart) * 10;
            char *output = new char[outsize];

            z_stream zstrm;
            zstrm.zalloc = Z_NULL;
            zstrm.zfree = Z_NULL;
            zstrm.opaque = Z_NULL;
            zstrm.avail_in = (uint)(streamend - streamstart + 1);
            zstrm.avail_out = (uint)outsize;
            zstrm.next_in = (Bytef *)(buffer + streamstart);
            zstrm.next_out = (Bytef *)output;

            int rsti = inflateInit(&zstrm);

            if (rsti == Z_OK) {
                int rst2 = inflate(&zstrm, Z_FINISH);
                inflateEnd(&zstrm);

                if (rst2 >= 0) {
                    size_t totout = zstrm.total_out;

                    //search and replace text code here

                    size_t coutsize = (streamend - streamstart + 1) * 10;
                    char *coutput = new char[coutsize];

                    z_stream c_stream;
                    c_stream.zalloc = Z_NULL;
                    c_stream.zfree = Z_NULL;
                    c_stream.opaque = Z_NULL;
                    c_stream.total_out = 0;
                    c_stream.avail_in = (uint)totout;
                    c_stream.avail_out = (uint)coutsize;
                    c_stream.next_in = (Bytef *)output;
                    c_stream.next_out = (Bytef *)coutput;

                    rsti = deflateInit(&c_stream, Z_DEFAULT_COMPRESSION);

                    if (rsti == Z_OK) {
                        rsti = deflate(&c_stream, Z_FINISH);
                        deflateEnd(&c_stream);

                        if (rsti >= 0) {
                            [self saveFile:coutput len:c_stream.total_out fileName:[destFile cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
                        }
                    }

                    delete [] coutput; coutput = 0;
                    [self saveFile:(char *)"\nendstr" len:7 fileName:[destFile cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
                }
            }

            delete[] output; output = 0;
            buffer += streamend + 7;
            filelen = filelen - (streamend + 7);
        } else {
            morestreams = false;
        }
    }

    [self saveFile:buffer len:filelen fileName:[destFile cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
}

fclose(pdfFile);
```

Comment: You write "//search and replace text code here"... exactly this is not trivial. As Bruno explained your search word may not be there in one character sequence and the characters may cine in a seemingly random order.  Your code  furthermore completely ignores font encodings up to here, so you likely won't find strings unless the font uses a standard encoding.

Comment: My problem now is not search and replace function, but when I decompress stream using zlib and compress it again, the final pdf is different than the original one, some text or graphics are missing.

Comment: You say you *replace text with other text.* Does the length remain? Your codes seems to assume that the length remained. Furthermore I don't see you updating any PDF stream length entries let alone the cross references. As the compressed size after your changes quite likely has changed, the result PDF very probably simply is broken. Furthermore I don't see you checking the type of stream you have. If you by chance change the streams containing images, they themselves likely are broken. Please provide a sample output PDF of your code to check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple issues in your code the effects of which are visible in the sample [newpdf.pdf](https://www.dropbox.com/s/hkvp11kj990vb8h/newpdf.pdf) you provided in a comment to Bruno's answer:

1. After you write your re-compressed stream to the output file, you add "\nendstr" and proceed the size of this string, 7, characters beyond the end of the source stream in the input buffer, most likely to prevent seeing the "stream" in "endstream" as the start of the next stream:

   ```
   [self saveFile:(char *)"\nendstr" len:7 fileName:[destFile cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
   [...]
   buffer += streamend + 7;
   ```

   The issue in adding that string is that you assume that the "endstream" in the input buffer is preceded by exactly one NEWLINE (0x0A) byte. This assumption is wrong because

   a. in PDF there are three types of valid end-of-line markers, a single LINE FEED (0x0A), a single CARRIAGE RETURN (0x0D), or a CARRIAGE RETURN and LINE FEED pair (0x0D 0x0A), and any one of these end-of-line markers may precede the "endstream" in the input buffer; in the code further above where you calculate the end of the compressed stream, you ignore the single CARRIAGE RETURN variety, and here you ignore the 2 byte variety; and furthermore:

   b. the [PDF specification](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf) does not even require but merely recommends to add an end-of-line between the end of the stream and the "endstream" keyword, cf. section 7.3.8.1:

   > There should be an end-of-line marker after the data and before **endstream**

   This already breaks the first stream in your sample file in which the source file does not have an end-of-line marker there and your result, therefore, replaces the original "endstream" with a "\nendstram". This actually happens fairly often in your sample.
2. You completely ignore that a PDF stream in its dictionary contains an entry containing the length of the stream, cf. section 7.3.8.2 in the [PDF specification](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf):

   > Every stream dictionary shall have a **Length** entry that indicates how many bytes of the PDF file are used for the stream’s data.

   Your manipulation, even if you only decompress and recompress, is likely to change the length of the compressed stream. Thus, you have to update that **Length** entry. This admittedly makes your task somewhat more difficult as that dictionary is *before* the stream. Furthermore, in cases like your source file, that entry might even not directly contain the value but instead reference an indirect object *somewhere else* in the file.

   This breaks the second stream in your file which claims it is 8150 bytes long but instead is some 200 bytes longer. Any PDF viewer may assume the content of that stream in your file is only 8150 bytes long and, thus, ignore the contents of those trailing 200 bytes. This may very well be the reason why you observed that

   > *some text or graphics are missing.*
3. You completely ignore that a PDF has a cross reference table or stream (or possibly even a chain of them), cf. section 7.5.4 in the [PDF specification](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf):

   > The cross-reference table contains information that permits random access to indirect objects within the file so that the entire file need not be read to locate any particular object. The table shall contain a one-line entry for each indirect object, specifying the byte offset of that object within the body of the file. (Beginning with PDF 1.5, some or all of the cross-reference information may alternatively be contained in cross-reference streams; see 7.5.8, "Cross-Reference Streams.")

   Your manipulation, even if you only decompress and recompress, is likely to change the length of the compressed stream. Thus, you have to update the offsets of all following objects in the cross reference table.

   As already the size of the second stream in your result file differs, only a very few cross reference entries in that file are correct.
4. You assume that every PDF stream is deflated. This assumption is wrong, cf. table 5 in the [PDF specification](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf).

   Your code essentially drops all streams it cannot inflate. This may also be a reason why you observed that

   > *some text or graphics are missing.*
5. You assume that the sequence "stream" in a PDF unambiguously indicates the start of a stream. This is wrong, that sequence may easily be used in other contexts, too.
6. You assume that the first sequence "endstream" in a PDF after the start of a stream unambiguously indicates the end of that stream. This is wrong, that sequence may also be part of the stream content. You have to use the value of the **Length** entry in the stream dictionary.

Furthermore you seem to assume that every stream you come along still is used in the resulting PDF. This does not need to be the case. Especially in case of incremental updates (cf. section 7.5.6 in the [PDF specification](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf)) there may be many objects in the file not in use anymore. While this does not necessarily break the syntax of the result file, your changes (if they depend on each other) are semantically incorrect.

Comment: Congratulations with the very comprehensive answer! +1

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. The code I use I found on the codeproject site and changed a little bit, so it can be wrong.

Comment: @BartoszBialecki It definitively is wrong. Actually most of the quick and easy solutions for PDF parsing and manipulating are broken and only work for a small subset of all PDFs if at all. A first indicator is whether or not the tool uses the cross references. If it does not, it most likely is trash.

Comment: @mkl you're right, I must look a bit closer at pdf specification and fix this. Thank you once again.

Answer (score 3):

Your assumption that text can be found literally in a content stream is wrong.

Suppose that you have a PDF with content Hello World. Then you could have a stream that looks like this:

```
q
BT
36 806 Td
0 -18 Td
/F1 12 Tf
(Hello World!)Tj
0 0 Td
ET
Q
```

But it can also look like this:

```
Q
BT
/F1 12 Tf
88.66 367 Td
(ld) Tj
-22 0 Td
(Wor) Tj
-15.33 0 Td
(llo) Tj
-15.33 0 Td
(He) Tj
ET
q
```

Your code will detect the word "Hello" in the former stream, but will miss it in the latter one.

A PDF viewer will render both streams in exactly the same way: you'll see "Hello World" at the exact same position.

Sometimes Strings are broken into smaller pieces, you'll often find text arrays to introduce kerning, etc... This is all standard practice in PDF.

PDF isn't a format that is suited for editing. I'm not saying it's impossible, but you're looking at a couple of weeks of extra programming if you want to meet your requirement of being able to replace one String with another one in a PDF stream.

Comment: And that's without regard to potentially modifying the layout when you replace "iii" with "mmm", since "i" and "m" are different size characters.

Comment: I understand that, but the problem is not with finding a text, but when I make inflate and then deflate, then some text are missing. So I think that inflate cannot decompress some data or deflate compress them.

Comment: Maybe you're corrupting XObjects, maybe you're making wrong assumptions about filters,... It's hard to tell. Download iText RUPS and compare the PDFs. RUPS is a tool that allows you to look inside a PDF.

Comment: I tested it with some pdf from apple developer site, so any documentation files from there does not work.

Comment: @BartoszBialecki More exactly: Please provide an *output PDF* your code created and which you consider faulty. Sorry if that wasn't clear.

Comment: The created pdf file has an error, but I opened it on the Mac OS X and on that system it was opened, so I didn't notice that. Here is link to the original pdf: https://www.dropbox.com/s/q632pzkadknxqul/testpdf.pdf and here to that created pdf: https://www.dropbox.com/s/hkvp11kj990vb8h/newpdf.pdf

Comment: @BartoszBialecki I analyzed your sample file and created an answer indicating a number of issues in your code resulting in the broken result file.

Answer (score 1):

i think you have to read about how the text is stored inside a PDF file,

here is a link to spec http://www.adobe.com/devnet/pdf/pdf_reference.html

section 9 Text is the key to understanding.